# Simplenews :How can i create newsletter template by simplenews

Tags: drupal

I have Drupal v7 and install simplenews, but now when i send a newsletter, i need to edit the html format.

Where can i edit this template ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text in the newsletter:
Go to contents -> Manage Content -> Newsletter (tab)

Here you will find your newsletter. Edit the content as you want.